# How to "merge" more than one 'ActiveRecord::Associations' and one or more scope methods?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and MySQL. *I would like to "merge" the result of more than one `ActiveRecord::Associations` and one or more scope methods*. That is, I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :a_user_relationships, :foreign_key => 'a_key'
  has_many :b_user_relationships, :foreign_key => 'b_key'

  has_many :a_articles, :through => :a_user_article_associations # Returns objects kind of 'Article'
  has_many :b_articles, :through => :b_user_article_associations # Returns objects kind of 'Article'
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Note: This is a scope method.
  def self.public
    where(:status => 'public')
  end
end
```

Given the above code I would like to run some method (as-like the following) so to retieve all *public* "a" and "b" user articles by executing as few as possible database queries:

```
@user.all_articles

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Note: Code in the following method is incorrect, but maybe it helps
  # understanding what I mean.
  def all_articles
    self.(a_articles & b_articles).public
    (self.a_articles.public & self.b_articles.public)
  end
end
```

**Is it possible?**

Comment: Is that really what the has_many relationships look like? How is :a_articles different than :b_articles? I ask because it could impact the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Tom L - Ops, I forgot to add `:through` statements. I updated the question.

Comment: I still don't have a clear picture of the associations. What's the difference between an 'a' user and a 'b' user? What is the association to User in the Article model?

Comment: @Tom L - I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two separate associations, you'll need at least two queries.

If you always want articles from both here, is there anything stopping you from having a simple "articles" association in addition to or instead of these two separate ones? That way, you could retrieve your articles with `self.articles.public`.

Comment: Yes, there is something stopping me from having a simple "articles": articles "a" and "b" have different kind of associations.

Comment: Feels like they should live on different tables, or at least be of different classes. They don't seem to be the same type of object.

Comment: I mean that article associations (in my case, `:a_user_relationships` and `:b_user_relationships`) "are" / "return" *different* "type" / "kind" of objects and that articles (in my case, `:a_articles` and `:b_articles`) "are" / "return" *same* "type" / "kind" of objects.